# Querying issues from Mysql database dump in MSR14 dataset challenge

Tags: mysql, database, github

MSR14 (http://2014.msrconf.org/challenge.php) provides challenge dataset in two forms - MySQL dump (106 MB) or MongoDB dump (2.7 GB).  They provide also the [database schema][1], [the data description and instructions][2] for importing and using the data.

My questions is, How could I run SQL queries to perform the following:

1. SQL query that should return a list of projects and each project
   assciated with list of issues classified as 'bug'.
2. SQL query that should return a list of projects and each project associated with list of pull requests that have be done on it.

I tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT p.url, p.name, p.language, i.issue_id, rl.name
FROM projects p, issues i, repo_labels rl
WHERE p.id = i.repo_id AND i.repo_id = rl.repo_id AND rl.name = 'BUG'
LIMIT 30;
```

and the results of that query, going to recall all the issues that classified as 'BUG' label but the problem, how could I get the body of each issue (i.e. text description).

In github, the pull request handle every thing which confused me when I want to retrive the data belong to bug issues. Also, there is a commits accostied to each issue, how could I know that I get all the commit to every pull request. It seems that I have a BIG confusion on understanding github pull request and commit techniques.

check the comment for references:

Comment: [1] http://ghtorrent.org/relational.html
  [2] http://ghtorrent.org/msr14.html

Comment: Isn't figuring that out part of the challenge?

Comment: No, the competition for this data-set finished, and I use this dataset for different purposes.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to show what you have tried, what you expected, and what didn't work. Be specific about error messages. As it stands, this question is in danger of being closed as "too broad".